# tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True) forces Horizontal Scrollbar disappearance when window resizes

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I've created a QTableWidget with these params.

```
def fill_table(self):
    self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(self.view_frame)
    self.tableWidget.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
    self.tableWidget.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
    self.tableWidget.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
    self.tableWidget.setShowGrid(False)
    self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(True)

    self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setHighlightSections(False)
    self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setProperty("showSortIndicator", True)
    self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)

    self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
    self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setHighlightSections(False)
    self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
    self.ui.tableWidget.setColumnCount(6)
    self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(self.zipped_log))
    self.ui.tableWidget.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
    self.ui.tableWidget.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
    self.ui.tableWidget.setVerticalScrollMode(QAbstractItemView.ScrollPerPixel)
    self.ui.tableWidget.setHorizontalScrollMode(QAbstractItemView.ScrollPerPixel)
    self.ui.tableWidget.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)


    for i in range(len(self.zipped_log)):
        self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(i, 0, QTableWidgetItem(str(self.zipped_log[i]['date'])))
        self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(i, 1, QTableWidgetItem(str(self.zipped_log[i]['time'])))
        self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(i, 2, QTableWidgetItem(self.zipped_log[i]['source']))
        self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(i, 3, QTableWidgetItem(self.zipped_log[i]['code']))
        self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(i, 4, QTableWidgetItem(str(self.zipped_log[i]['severity'])))
        self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(i, 5, QTableWidgetItem(self.zipped_log[i]['description']))

    self.ui.tableWidget.resizeColumnsToContents()
    self.ui.tableWidget.resizeRowsToContents()
    self.ui.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)

def resizeEvent(self, event):
    self.ui.tableWidget.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
    self.ui.tableWidget.setWordWrap(False)
    QMainWindow.resizeEvent(self, event)
```

All works well, except filling the table with different content and resizing the window.

In first step i fill the table with short rows, which suit the size of the window. If i call filling function again, with long rows, which doesn't suit the size of the window, these rows will activate the horizontal scrollbar and all works well, i can scroll them horizontally. But long rows start wordwrapping after resizing the window, and i can't scroll them with horizontal scrollbar anymore.

It looks like three dots `...` at the not actual end of the row but at the edge of the window.

I've already tried to use resizeEvent, but it didn't help.

How can i fix this problem? I want a dynamic horizontal ScrollBar, which will show as needed and rows will not be wordwrapped after resizing the window

Answer (score 1):

The `setStretchLastSection()` changes the resize mode of the last section to the `QHeaderView.Stretch`. In the `Stretch` mode, the section always fills the available space whether contents of the column are wider than it or not, so the horizontal scrollbar will not appear. (The section size will not grow to fit contents of the column.)

So, I recommend not using the `setStretchLastSection()` if you use the `QTableView.resizeColumnsToContents()`.

If you don't mind resizing columns manually in a hacky way, you can do this. (It's hacky because it may be broken in a future Qt version.)

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
...

def resize_tableview_columns(tableview):
    tableview.resizeColumnsToContents()
    def on_idle():
        if not tableview.horizontalScrollBar().isVisible():
            header = tableview.horizontalHeader()
            last_col = header.count() - 1
            header.resizeSection(last_col, tableview.viewport().width() -
                sum(header.sectionSize(i) for i in range(last_col)))
    QTimer.singleShot(0, on_idle)

...

def fill_table(self):
    self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(self.view_frame)
    ...
    #self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True) # Don't do this.
    ...
    #self.ui.tableWidget.resizeColumnsToContents() # Use the below instead of this.
    resize_tableview_columns(self.ui.tableWidget)
    ...
    #self.ui.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True) # Don't do this.
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem was that table remembered the longest row length and used it even with different file with shorter rows. So, i just update the last section every time i refill the table with the contents.
I've solved the problem like that:

in MainClass:

```
def resizeEvent(self, event):
   self.ui.tableWidget.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
   self.ui.tableWidget.setWordWrap(False)
   QMainWindow.resizeEvent(self, event)

def fill_table(self):
   self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(False)
   ...
   filling the table
   ...
   self.tableWidget.resizeColumnsToContents()
   self.tableWidget.resizeRowsToContents()
   self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
```